# I want to reset the grid through Reset button

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

```
public class ButtonGrid extends JFrame{


private final JButton[][] grid;
private int length,width;

public ButtonGrid(int width,int length){

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    panel.add(start);
    //start.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(reset);

    add(panel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,length));
    grid = new JButton[width][length];

    for(int y=0; y<length; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
            grid[x][y]=new JButton();
            grid[x][y].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            panel1.add(grid[x][y]);
            grid[x][y].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    Object source = e.getSource();
                    JButton b1 = (JButton)source;
                    if(b1 == source){
                    b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
            });
            reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    Object source = e.getSource();
                    JButton b1 = (JButton)source;
                    if(b1 == source){
                    b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                }
                }
            });
            }
    }


    add(panel1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);

    setSize(600,600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
        public static void main(String[] args) {
     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     ButtonGrid bg = new ButtonGrid(25,25);
      }
     });
    }
}
```

In this code I am able to change background of the buttons in the grid but I want to reset the grid by changing the background to WHITE again. I am not able to do this since my actionListener does not allow to set background using grid[x][y]. Please help how do I proceed in this.

Comment: What does the reset button ought to do? Reset *all* buttons?

Comment: Note: the `if(b1 == source)` checks are unnecessary. Your `ActionListener` will only get invoked by the button at which you registered it and nothing else.

Comment: more importantly you are adding actionlistener to reset inside a for loop. It seems nonsense to me. Your `grid[]][]` is declared in class context. Sure you can access it from any member method or nested class.

Comment: @Hafiz, it is better you go through the code yourself. And keep asking the question as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: When I click on reset button I want to change the background of all the buttons in a grid to white. So I want to access all the Buttons in a grid through action listener of Reset button so that I can change the background to white.

Comment: Thanks Holger appreciate your help

Comment: I also want to add an action listener for Start Button which takes buttons with Black background as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able to do this since my actionListener does not allow to set background using grid[x][y].

Sure you can do this. The `grid` variable is an instance variable so you can access it directly in your ActionListener. So the code in your ActionListener would be a loop that iterates through both dimensions of your array and then sets the background of each button

```
for(int y=0; y<length; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
            grid[x][y].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
         }
}
```

Also, you should not be creating a separate ActionListener for each button. You can share the listener with code like:

```
ActionListener black = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        JButton b1 = (JButton)source;
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
};

for(int y=0; y<length; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
            grid[x][y]=new JButton();
            grid[x][y].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            panel1.add(grid[x][y]);
            grid[x][y].addActionListener(black);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that an `ActionListener` will only get invoked by the button at which it was registered. So you don’t have to compare the source of the event.

The following code will reset all buttons by registering multiple `ActionListener`s which are all invoked when the reset button is clicked:

```
for(int y=0; y<length; y++){
    for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
        final JButton b=new JButton();
        grid[x][y]=b;
        b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel1.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                b.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        });
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use one listener for setting the background and one reset listener which iterates over all buttons:

```
ActionListener black=new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
};
for(int y=0; y<length; y++){
    for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
        final JButton b=new JButton();
        grid[x][y]=b;
        b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel1.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(black);
    }
}
reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        for(JButton[] buttons:grid)
            for(JButton b:buttons)
                b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
});
```